# how to view pdf stream in PDF.JS?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, stream, pdf.js

I'm using Spring MVC framework. and PDFJS.version = '1.1.215'.
Want to display the PDF content in PDF.JS.
PDF contents located server side, so i think cant use URL of PDF on jsp...

Controller source

```
@RequestMapping("/viewer.do")
public BufferedOutputStream viewer(... svo
, HttpServletRequest request
, HttpServletResponse response
, ModelMap model) throw Exception{

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try{
    File pdfFile = new File("C:\\test.pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
    int size = fis.available();
    byte[] buf = new byte[size];
    int readCount = fis.read(buf);

    response.flushBuffer();
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    bos.write(buf, 0, readCount);
    bos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e){}

    return bos;
}
```

Want to display this pdf stream in pdf.js. please help me.

Comment: Make sure you set Content-Length header and make sure server doesn't set Accept-Ranges header (since your script cannot handle range requests).